# Chat in SpringBoot and Angular - Specific User messages

Tags: angular, websocket, chat, spring-websocket, stomp

I would like to implement chat in our application based on the Angular client and SpringBoot Websocket server. I ran into this article, which works great (https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-websocket) . My problem is that I would like to write the messages to **particular user** (or group of users, f.i helpdesk) not to everybody. What I find so far is that I need to use **queue instead of topics** and send user in header (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-websockets-sendtouser). Could somebody point me to some working example, most preferably in Anuglar and SpringBoot combination.

Many thanks

Comment: Was there any approach done ? Please share the updates